# Calculate time difference in mysql in case it is midnight

Tags: mysql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am calculating the time difference as follows:

```
SELECT SUBTIME(DATE_FORMAT(`DataChegada`,'%H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(`Datasaida`,'%H:%i')) AS `Horas Consumidas` FROM raddb.RegistoAcompa
```

The problem is that I have the following situation:

`Datasaida` = '2022-07-13 21:00:00'
`DataChegada` = '2022-07-14 00:00:00'

The time difference is 3 hours but it is returning '-21:00:00' hours. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: instead of `%H:%i`, does it work if you include the full date too like `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` (syntax from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I can get the correct result this way: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, Datasaida, DataChegada) AS Testeee FROM raddb.RegistoAcompa`, only the result is 3 and I intended it to return like this '03:00:00'. 
can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both columns are datetimes you should use [`TIMEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(`DataChegada`, `Datasaida`) AS `Horas Consumidas` 
FROM raddb.RegistoAcompa
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed, but the result is 3. I wanted it to return 03:00:00, can you help to solve this problem?

Comment: @Junior The result is 03:00:00. Check it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf32ae5ea82a1ac88541fe510d365a91